# Rubymine Linux - No Ruby interpreter configured for the project

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-14.04, rubymine

I decided to get RubyMine 8.0 (the student edition).

I have already installed Ruby, and I can run Ruby scripts from the Terminal. But, I can't make RubyMine detect this interpreter and I can't seem to set it up.

Are there any required gems? What are gems?

[[image: I get this error]]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/configuring-ruby-sdk.html - how did you choose the interpreter that seems to be selected in your SS?

Comment: @Amadan above the local and remote option there was a /usr/bin/ruby option. Same thing happens if i choose that file from the local option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to click on 'V' button first (situated under '+' and '-') and then on 'Apply', which will become available.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometimes i amaze myself with how dumb i can get